# Sentry io send email

Tags: laravel, sentry

How to send Sentry alert notify to custom emails that have been field in my web app? I try to edit user config using sentry api , but it is not such method in api

Comment: The Sentry api does not allow this https://docs.sentry.io/api/

Comment: Have another way for solved this problem ?

Comment: You need to check in with sentry support whether it's possible what you are asking

Comment: I asked , but it still silence